# Discriminant Analysis (FDA and MDA) plots in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to plot the results of Flexible discriminant analysis(FDA) and Mixture discriminant analysis(MDA) using the `mda` and `ggplot2` package. I did it for Linear discriminant analysis(LDA) but I do not know to continue. Any help or ideas how to code these graphs using ggplot2?

Code:

```
require(MASS)
require(ggplot2)
require(mda)
require(scales)
  
irislda <- lda(Species ~ ., iris)

prop.lda = irislda$svd^2/sum(irislda$svd^2)
plda <- predict(irislda,   iris)

dataset = data.frame(species = iris[,"Species"], irislda = plda$x)
p1 <- ggplot(dataset) + geom_point(aes(irislda.LD1, irislda.LD2, colour = species, shape = species), size = 2.5) + 
  labs(x = paste("LD1 (", percent(prop.lda[1]), ")", sep=""),
       y = paste("LD2 (", percent(prop.lda[2]), ")", sep=""))
p1 

irisfda <- fda(Species ~ ., data = iris, method = mars)
 
irismda <- mda(Species ~ ., data = iris)
```

Comment: OP, can you clarify how we can help you?  Is your question related to coding or statistics?  If you have a statistical question related to MDA, perhaps your question is better suited to a statistics or math-based community?  If your question relates to getting the code to work, then by all means clarify the question here.

Comment: Thanks, changed it. My problem is how to code it to a graph using ggplot2.

Answer (score 3):

I believe this gets to what you are after. The fda model only has two dimensions, so it is explaining 100%. The mda model had 5 dimensions, so I am only showing the two that explain the most.

```
library(dplyr)
irisfda <- fda(Species ~ ., data = iris, method = mars)

irisfda$fit$fitted.values %>% 
  as_tibble() %>% 
  bind_cols(species = iris[,"Species"]) %>%
  ggplot() +
  geom_point(aes(V1, V2, color = species, shape = species), size = 2.5) + 
  labs(x = paste("FDA1 (", percent(irisfda$percent.explained[1]/100), ")", sep=""),
       y = paste("FDA2 (", percent(irisfda$percent.explained[2]/100 - irisfda$percent.explained[1]/100), ")", sep=""))
```

[image: fda model]

```
irismda <- mda(Species ~ ., data = iris)

irismda$fit$fitted.values %>% 
  as_tibble() %>% 
  bind_cols(species = iris[,"Species"]) %>% 
  ggplot() +
  geom_point(aes(V1, V2, color = species, shape = species), size = 2.5) + 
  labs(x = paste("MDA1 (", percent(irismda$percent.explained[1]/100), ")", sep=""),
       y = paste("MDA2 (", percent(irismda$percent.explained[2]/100 - irismda$percent.explained[1]/100), ")", sep=""))
```

[image: mda model]

**EDIT:**

To get rid of the warning that you are seeing, we can name the columns of the matrix before passing it to `as_tibble`. This edit does not use the `%>%` operator.

```
colnames(irisfda$fit$fitted.values) <- c("V1", "V2")
df1 <- bind_cols(as_tibble(irisfda$fit$fitted.values),
                 species = iris[,"Species"])
ggplot(df1) +
  geom_point(aes(V1, V2, color = species, shape = species), size = 2.5) + 
  labs(x = paste("FDA1 (", percent(irisfda$percent.explained[1]/100), ")", sep=""),
       y = paste("FDA2 (", percent(irisfda$percent.explained[2]/100 - irisfda$percent.explained[1]/100), ")", sep=""))


colnames(irismda$fit$fitted.values) <- c("V1", "V2", "V3", "V4", "V5", "V6", "V7", "V8") 
df2 <- bind_cols(as_tibble(irismda$fit$fitted.values), 
                 species = iris[,"Species"])
ggplot(df2) +
  geom_point(aes(V1, V2, color = species, shape = species), size = 2.5) + 
  labs(x = paste("MDA1 (", percent(irismda$percent.explained[1]/100), ")", sep=""),
       y = paste("MDA2 (", percent(irismda$percent.explained[2]/100 - irismda$percent.explained[1]/100), ")", sep=""))
```

**EDIT 2:**
It seems that you don't want to use `dplyr` so I am including base R functions here with the `ggplot` plot.

```
require(MASS)
require(ggplot2)
require(mda)
require(scales)
irisfda <- fda(Species ~ ., data = iris, method = mars)

irismda <- mda(Species ~ ., data = iris)

df1 <- cbind(data.frame(irisfda$fit$fitted.values),
                 species = iris[,"Species"])
ggplot(df1) +
  geom_point(aes(X1, X2, color = species, shape = species), size = 2.5) + 
  labs(x = paste("FDA1 (", percent(irisfda$percent.explained[1]/100), ")", sep=""),
       y = paste("FDA2 (", percent(irisfda$percent.explained[2]/100 - irisfda$percent.explained[1]/100), ")", sep=""))


df2 <- cbind(data.frame(irismda$fit$fitted.values), 
                 species = iris[,"Species"])
ggplot(df2) +
  geom_point(aes(X1, X2, color = species, shape = species), size = 2.5) + 
  labs(x = paste("MDA1 (", percent(irismda$percent.explained[1]/100), ")", sep=""),
       y = paste("MDA2 (", percent(irismda$percent.explained[2]/100 - irismda$percent.explained[1]/100), ")", sep=""))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Is it possible to provide a version without the `%>%`. It will help me to understand it better. There is a warning related to the tidyverse package:
**`Warning message: The `x` argument of `as_tibble.matrix()` must have column names if `.name_repair` is omitted as of tibble 2.0.0. Using compatibility `.name_repair`. This warning is displayed once every 8 hours. Call `lifecycle::last_warnings()` to see where this warning was generated.**

Comment: I have edited the answer to address the two things you brought up.

Comment: Cool. Can you also add a solution only with data frame without tibble and %>%

Comment: @JohnSal I edited to only use base functions (i.e. no tibble and no %>%).